# Twig templates for nodes in different views

Tags: theming, 8

I have a content type, `blog_post`, that is displayed by a number of different views.

I'm having a problem that the node template that gets used first after clearing the cache will then be used for all other views.

For example one page displays a view called "Blog Posts". If I load this page after clearing the cache, it correctly uses the template `node--view--blog-posts.html.twig`.

Another page uses the view "Latest Blog Posts", and this should use the template, `node--view--latest-blog-posts.html.twig`. However if I load this page without clearing the cache first, it uses the `node--view--blog-posts.html.twig` template.

If I clear the cache and reload the second page, it will then use the correct template, but if I go back to the first page, it will be using the template for the second!

I have twig debugging enabled, and it shows the wrong view name under "FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS" as follows:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * node--view--blog-posts--page.html.twig
   x node--view--blog-posts.html.twig
   * node--20--teaser.html.twig
   * node--20.html.twig
   * node--blog-post--teaser.html.twig
   * node--blog-post.html.twig
   * node--teaser.html.twig
   * node.html.twig
-->
```

I expect that lots of other sites theme nodes in multiple views, so I expect I'm done something wrong. Any suggestions how I can debug this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use node--view-* templates. They are broken.

[Two views with entity view mix up rendered templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/2838950)

The quick solution:

- create unique view mode for your CT
- display views with content
- use unique view mode for your view

Comment: Thanks! So in the above example, my template would become `node--blog-post--teaser.html.twig`, and if I create a view mode called "Latest" and use it for my view, the template would become `node--blog-post--latest.html.twig`?

Comment: Yes, you can see this suggestion like in your example.

Comment: Brilliant. I will try this tonight. It would appear that this bug has been known for a year and a half, and no fix in sight.

Comment: Brilliant! That's working perfectly now. I must admit I hadn't realised how useful custom view modes are. I suspect I will be using a lot of them in the future!